# Android: Autocomplete.IntentBuilder

Tags: android, kotlin, autocomplete, google-places-api

There's been some updates for the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) on Android

I would like to send an additional Int Extra after using the `Autocomplete.IntentBuilder`

Kotlin example:

```
val fields = arrayListOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)
var intent = 
        Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, 
            fields
        ).build(this)

intent.putExtra("test", someId)
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

But `onActivityResult`'s intent doesn't receive the additional extra after using `intent.getIntExtra("test", 0)`

Is there a way to add on to what the IntentBuilder is doing?

Comment: but you can take a global variable instead of passing it in the AutocompleteActivity because you want to access it in the same activity and also another reason is that you can not put modified value of "test" on finish of AutocompleteActivity because we can not handle onbackpress() or finish() of AutocompleteActivity.